# Setting up BLE modules

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, arduino-uno, spi, adafruit

I am using an adafruit BLE SPI friend, an nRF51 series BLE module.  Eventually I will have to set it up to work with an STM32 microcontroller.  Is it better to program it with a SPI library on an arduino uno to receive BLE data on a bluetooth receiver (iphone), or should I use any kind of Nordic Semiconductors/program IDE to make the device programming more robust. I would also like to add GATT settings, but really this is my first time working with SPI BLE so I'm not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions? (Also, I am not sure the adafruit library for the device is all that helpful, it seems to sacrifice bandwidth and some functionality for compatibility with their bluefruit app and other of their devices)

Comment: Why are you reluctant to use the nRF51 directly? They're relatively easy to use and there are a ton of applications and tutorials that can get you started.

Comment: originally to test out the device before using it for a project, but since then I have realized it really limits what I can do. I will try to move to those nordic semi sdk's and their APIs and push for ordering the nrf51822